# Should Controls Be in the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am trying to learn MVVM and using MVVM light with my phone application but I am kinda confused on how to access some information.

I am trying to not to use code behind events as much as possible as that does not seem to be the true MVVM way but I ran into a problem I don't know how to do.

I am using Google authentication and I am checking the Naviagted Event after each browser load.

```
public ICommand BrowserNavigated
{
   get
   {
      return new RelayCommand<NavigationEventArgs>(e =>
      {
         var d = e;
         var a = d;
      });
   }
}
```

However I also need the actual object control(I want to access the html that page is spitting back out) but I don't know how to get it.

```
 private void wbGoogle_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var d = e;
        var d2 = d;
    }
```

in the above code I could just cast "sender" to a web browser object but with me doing it the MVVM way I don't know how to access it.

Should I have another property or something for WebBrowser in my ViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVVM, code behind is allowed, but perhaps bindings are preferred. However, having GUI controls / events (hard coupling) is not allowed.

There may be ways to avoid code behind, but if you have to handle an event, get the data out of the event and set the property on your ViewModel in your code behind, then that is a better way to do it than adding UI code to your ViewModel which is clearly not keeping with MVVM.

Perhaps you can create some sort of EventTrigger which sets a property for a webbrowser that you can databind to create a re-usable Trigger that you can set in your XAML? (There's probably lots of ways to be clever on how to avoid code behind and create reusable code)

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewModel should be totally unaware of the View or particular controls. Whether or not to keep the codebehind of your view clear or not, is a matter of religion.

If you want to keep it clean, which I recommend whenever possible, there are a number of concepts, which allow you to do so.

First, you need to design your View/ViewModel relationship in a way, that all data relevant for the ViewModel is present 'at all times' in the ViewModel or can be passed to the ViewModel via `CommandParameter` of a `ICommand`. In your case, if the page of the Webbrowser is controlled by (i.e. might be set from) the ViewModel, the ViewModel should hold a property, which is bound to the `Source` property of the browser. If the ViewModel just needs to 'know' the Uri when the `BrowserNavigated` is executed, just pass it as a `CommandParameter`.

Secondly, for your particular case, you want to execute a command on the ViewModel, when the `Navigated` event of the WebBrowser is raised. As always, there are several options. I prefer the option which comes with the framework: The `EventTrigger` in `System.Windows.Interactivity` allows you to relay any event of any control to commands via bindings.

This way, the Uri can be set from the ViewModel:

```
<WebBrowser Source="{Binding BrowserPageUri}" Name="wbGoogle">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Navigated" >
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding BrowserNavigated}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</WebBrowser>
```

This way, you can handle the Uri as parameter of the command:

```
<WebBrowser Name="wbGoogle">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Navigated" >
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding BrowserNavigated}" 
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding Source, ElementName=wbGoogle}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </WebBrowser>
```

Of course, this only lets you access the Uri of the page in the WebBrowser, not the page itself. If you need to bind to the page object itself, you need to extend the WebBrowser, with an attached property, that makes the `Document` property bindable. This is quite straight-forward:

[Attached Document property for WebBrowser](http://www.michelvandervlugt.net/PermaLink,guid,a31d5ba1-cf6a-46c7-a4ff-7cecd7308fcc.aspx)

After attaching this property to your WebBrowser, you can define the bindings of the WebBrowser just as in the above code, just with the attached property, instead of the `Source` property.

Note, that the syntax for binding to an attached property would be:

```
{Binding Path=(WebBrowserExtentions.Document)}
```

Answer (score 0):

MVVM can be great for data binding and by using toolkits like MVVMLight, events that deal with user interactions can also be neatly dealt with.

However sometimes, controls like `WebBrowserControl` or `ApplicationBar` present a challenge to this. They can be difficult or impossible to bind with event triggers, or have complex behaviours. In these cases it is simpler if you handle the process of getting information from the control in your View code behind and send a simple message down to the VM.

Sure you could create an event that updates a property, write an Attached Property, or maybe use a 3rd party library; and there are cases that warrant that approach.

In your example I personally *would* use code-behind to handle the `Navigated` event and send down a message (or a method call on your VM) containing everything the VM wants in one go.

For instance:

```
private void wbGoogle_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var vm = (TypeOfMyViewModel) this.DataContext;
    //... read your HTML, get URL etc ...
    vm.WebBrowserNavigatedTo(url, html, loadTime);
}
```

Similarly if an event raised from your VM would cause many things to happen in your View there comes a point where it is simpler to send a message or event to your View and let the View update the controls in code.

The key thing is keep the roles of MVVM distinct, e.g. to avoid a direct dependency of the ViewModel on the View. Interfaces can help here well as Messaging that comes with MVVMLight and its alternatives.

Comment: Ya that is what I am thinking of doing just using the code behind events for web browser. Not sure what you mean by " send down a message (or a method call on your VM) containing everything the VM wants in one go." Also any other events where it is just better to use code behind?

Comment: Another thing that confuses me is how do you do like progress bars if your using MVVM? I think I seen people use like the visibility in the VM but is that not like bringing UI controls to the VM?

Comment: Answer updated with an code example. One common way of doing the visibility is to use a simple `ValueConverter` that converts from bool to `Visibility`. Should be easy enough to find an example with Google.

Comment: Where is "this.DataContext" coming from? Mine is always null.